# Oracle Sql-developer issue with viewing table's tabs for data, constraints, columns etc

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I can access my database and view all tables list with Oracle SQL Developer. But when I click on a table and try to view list of tabs for data, constraints, columns etc... I don't see anything on them. I use SQL Developer Version 3.0.04 with JDK 6. The only tab that shows up with content is "SQL".

Answer (score 1):

Oracle SQL Developer 3.1 (3.1.07.42) is just out; [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) and install this. Your installation must be broken as 3.0.04 works perfectly (using JDK 6u25). While you are at it, you should probably upgrade to [JDK 6u30](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u30-download-1377139.html) as well if you are not yet using it.